# Python generics: How to infer generic type from class attribute?

Tags: python, generics

Let's say I have a number of requests types each of which correspond to exactly one reponse type. Each request is represented as a subclasse of the Request class.

I also have a function which takes a Request as an argument and returns the response (of the corresponding type). I would like to get a static type hint about the concrete response type depending on which Request subclass was passed.

I tried doing it like so:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type

ResponseType = TypeVar("ResponseType")


class Request(Generic[ResponseType]):
    response_type: Type[ResponseType]


class IsProcessedStartedRequest(Request):
    response_type = bool


class GetIdRequest(Request):
    response_type = str


def send_request(request: Request[ResponseType]) -> ResponseType:
    ...


request = GetIdRequest()   # inferred type: GetIdRequest
response = send_request(request)        # inferred type: Any
```

However, the inferred type of the response variable is not 'str' as I would expect, but 'Any'.

P.S. I'm referring to the type hints which my IDE provides (PyCharm).

**UPD:**
I also figured that I could add a generic parameter to the definiton of the subclasses:

```py
class GetIdRequest(Request[str]):
```

but this still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: FWIW, your code example infers the correct `str` type today, using Python 3.6.8 and mypy  0.910, when using the generic parameter like `class GetIdRequest(Request[str])`. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this typechecks correctly in PyCharm:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

ResponseType = TypeVar("ResponseType")


class Request(Generic[ResponseType]):
    ...


class IsProcessedStartedRequest(Request[bool]):
    ...


class GetIdRequest(Request[str]):
    ...


def send_request(request: Request[ResponseType]) -> ResponseType:
    ...


request = GetIdRequest()             # inferred type: GetIdRequest
response = send_request(request)     # inferred type: str
```